# Como trabalhar com AngularJS sem a API estar pronta?

Tags: html5, angularjs

Quero fazer o *front-end* da minha aplicação com *AngularJS* só que minha API RESTFul ainda não está pronta para ser consumida, tem alguma ferramenta que me auxilie para trabalhar os retornos em JSON?

Comment: Você pode instalar um extensão para Chrome:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem essa: http://johansson.jp/angular-apimock

Exemplo no github: https://github.com/seriema/angular-apimock/blob/gh-pages-dev/app/scripts/controllers/demo-simple.js

Answer (score 1):

Não conheço nenhuma API, porém você pode fazer da seguinte forma.

`$scope.jsonTeste = { "prop": true, "prop2": false }` // Adiciona seu json aqui.

depois você altera para sua request.

```
$http(url).then(function(retorno) { $scope.jsonTeste = retorno.data  } );
```

logo que uma coisa não depende da outra, e pode ser desenvolvida completamente a parte.